# An incompatible authentication configuration was found in this project ()

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently working on an AAD migration. So prior to it it was Windows authentication. I disabled in the Web.config & in .csproj as mentioned in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934908/visual-studio-configure-azure-ad-authentication-says-windows-authentication-is-c)

But this time it's giving me the error "**An incompatible authentication configuration was found in this project ()**". I have no idea what is it. In the Entire project, the only Single Web.config file is there. Please help out if someone have fixed this .

Comment: Any response Here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we have 2 options to migrate an application to AAD from different authentication process.

1. You can directly Right Click on the project & try for the option "Configure AAD Authentication". Simply select it & provide the required data & It flies as expected. IN My case this way didn't worked as it was a Old application & although it was in 4.5 Framework still some how due to initial setup dependencies it was not working.
2. 2nd way is, To create a separate new application & implement the AAD process then try to get this project added in to the new project. This was helped me .

Answer (score 4):

I had recently the same problem trying to run the AAD Authentication wizard on a simple Asp.Net Core 2.2 App with no authentication set.

Message : "An incompatible authentication configuration was found in this project (Individual User Accounts)"

Cause : appsettings.json file with a ConnectionString named "DefaultConnection" :

> "ConnectionStrings": {
>       "DefaultConnection": ""   }